# aChartEngine: How to add padding between the chart and the y-axis labels

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using `aChartEngine` to display a simple bar chart. I would like to add padding between the chart itself and the y-axis labels. The labels touch the border of the chart, which doesn't look too great. I know of the `setMargins` method of the `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` class, but this just controls the outer margins of the chart as a whole. How would I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the alignment of the Y axis labels and you can change the font size and style, but you cannot change the padding between the labels and the chart itself.

I have just added APIs for setting the padding for both X and Y axis.

```
renderer.setXLabelsPadding(10);
renderer.setYLabelsPadding(10);
```

You can checkout the code from the AChartEngine SVN and build a jar file using `ant dist`.

Comment: @dan hii i have same problem but i cant find the method XYMultipleSeriesRenderer in this class object.so any lib or any thing else.. i am facing same problem my x-label touches the y label in corner.so tell me the review?

Comment: Thanks it works. These functions are now included in the newest version 1.1.0: https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list

Comment: It kinda sucks, it's not compatible with other jars from achartengine

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines

```
    multiRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Paint.Align.RIGHT);
    multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{0, 70, 0, 0});
    multiRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(15);
```